# Symfony Doctrine create query with ManyToMany relations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have relation ManyToMant photo and tag and I need find photo which have exactly some tags id, I try "in" function, but when I send two tag id (1, 2) I have photo which have one tag with id 1. How to find photo which have exactly some tag ids?

thisis my entity

```
class Photo
{   
use Timestampable;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Annotation\Groups({
 *     "get_photo"
 * })
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var Tags[]|ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tags", inversedBy="photo")
 * @Annotation\Type("Relation<AppBundle\Entity\Tags>")
 * @Annotation\SerializedName("tag_ids")
 * @Annotation\Accessor(setter="setSerializedTag")
 * @Annotation\Groups({
 *     "post_photo", "get_photo", "put_photo"
 * })
 */
protected $tags;
```

and Tags

```
class Tags
{  
use Timestampable;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Annotation\Groups({"get_tag"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var Photo[]|ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Photo", mappedBy="tags")
 */
protected $photo;
```

and my query, in `$parameterBag->get('tag_ids')` example [1, 2]:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getPhotoByParameters(
    ParameterBag $parameterBag,        
) {
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
        ->select('p')
        ->from('AppBundle:Photo', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('p.tags', 't');
    
    if ($parameterBag->get('tag_ids') !== null
        && is_array($tagIds = $parameterBag->get('tag_ids'))
    ) {
        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('t.id', $parameterBag->get('tag_ids')));
    }

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();

    return $results;
}
```

and after in result I need have photo which have and tag 1 and tag id 2. Not only tag with id 1 example or 2

when try

```
            $andX = $qb->expr()->andX();
        foreach ($tagIds as $id) {
            $andX->add($qb->expr()->eq('t.id', $id));
        }
        $qb->andWhere($andX);
```

I have 0 photo (when get > 1 tag id), when get = 1 tag id I have response with my photo

when try like this have something like "in"

```
        $orX = $qb->expr()->orX();
        foreach ($tagIds as $id) {
            $orX->add($qb->expr()->eq('t.id', $id));
        }
        $qb->andWhere($orX);
```

photos who have on or more tag ids from query

Comment: This `is_array($tagIds = $parameterBag->get('tag_ids')` is ugly.

Comment: @keyboardSmasher what your proposition for more pretty  this parameters ?

Comment: I'm just saying that that's a hell of a place to define a variable.

Comment: Why? If I have some filter with some parameters and this parameters have required false - I created ParameterBag variable and get this variable to repository entity, then check if this variable to be - my query have dynamic add some condition. I know, for request can created model and get model to repo, but if another domain call this repo function  - another domain don't have this model and in this situation I again created ParameterBag variable, it is very convenient, I think

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue

```
        if ($parameterBag->get('tag_ids') !== null
        && is_array($tagIds = $parameterBag->get('tag_ids'))
    ) {
        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('t.id', $parameterBag->get('tag_ids')));
        $qb->groupBy('p.id');
        $qb->having('COUNT(t.id) = :tagIds');
        $qb->setParameter('tagIds', count($parameterBag->get('tag_ids')));
    }
```

1. first I filter all photo who have some tag ids - example 1 and 2
2. then I checking if then photo have exectly quantity

thats all